# EXPO push notification after build REACT NATİVE

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo

I developed an expo project and finally I want to add push notifications. everything is fine.
I run this function after the state of log in componentdidmount function in app.js is true.
function this link is created as a reference
[expo official overview](http://https:%20//docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/)

```
registerForPushNotifications = async () =>
{
  const {status} = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
  let finalStatus = status;

  if(status !=='granted')
  {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    finalStatus= status ; 
  }

  if (finalStatus!=='granted') {return;}
 let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
    console.log("tokentokentokentokentokentoken");
    console.log(token);
    
    Fire.shared.firestore
                .collection("users")
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .update({
                    tokenForPush: token
                }) 

    
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }
 
}
```

Then I open the expo application from my android phone that I use. I connect to the project and the value of  ***tokenForPush***  variable in the user collection in the firestore is changed.
no problem so far.
Then I created the send notification function and this token is successfully sent to the notification expo application when it is open.

However, the part I do not understand is that when I run the expo build: android command, I can get builds smoothly and download from the relevant link.

I download and send the apk to the phone with the same android operating system via whatsapp and install it.

The application opens without any problems, but when I log in after it is opened, I cannot assign a value to tokenForPush on the firestore side. So the value does not change at the same time.

This expo push notification package is only valid for the expo application, right? I have API I can fetch it, but can I only get notifications from the expo mobile app? What is the point if I cannot get notifications after getting a build or after converting to a real app (after the apk file)? I am very confused. Can you help me?

OR how to set up push notification on my expo project without expo ejecting?